# live updating edit field when slider value is changing

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a slider and a edit field, which are defined as

```
uicontrol(fig,'Style','Slider','Units','characters','Position',[17.1+f*iwidth 10.5 4 28.6],'Min',0,'Max',1000,'Value',500,'SliderStep', [1/500 , 10/500 ],'Callback','evaluation_callbacks(''results'',guidata(gcbo))','Tag',['slider' int2str(f)]);

uicontrol(fig,'Style','Edit','Enable','inactive','Units','characters','Position',[14+f*iwidth 8.2 9 1.6],'FontSize',10,'String',500,'Tag',['rating' int2str(f)]);
```

With the following Callback functions:

```
function evaluation_callbacks(varargin)

% EVALUATION_CALLBACKS   Callback functions for the evaluation interface
%
% evaluation_callbacks(fname,varargin) executes the callback function
% fname_callback with various parameters

fname=[varargin{1},'_callback'];
feval(fname,varargin{2:end});



%%%saving the rating results and proceeding to the next experiment or exiting
function results_callback(handles)

% stop audio
clear sound

%getting the ratings for all files
for f=1:handles.nbfile
    handles.ratings(handles.expe_order(handles.expe),handles.file_order(f))=get(getfield(handles,['slider' int2str(f)]),'Value');
end
%saving the whole results (to avoid losing data if the program terminates early)
results='';
fid=fopen(handles.resultfile,'w');
for e=1:handles.nbexpe
    for f=1:handles.nbfile
    fprintf(fid,'%d\n',handles.ratings(e,f));
    end
end

fclose(fid);
if handles.expe<handles.nbexpe
    handles.expe=handles.expe+1;
    % updating title
    set(handles.experiment,'String',handles.parameter{handles.expe});
    % update evaluation parameters
    set(handles.scale90,'String',handles.high{handles.expe});
    set(handles.scale10,'String',handles.low{handles.expe});

    if handles.expe==handles.nbexpe
        pos=get(handles.results,'Position');
        pos(1)=pos(1)+2.5;
        pos(3)=19;
        set(handles.results,'Position',pos,'String','Save and exit');
    end
    %moving all the sliders back to 50
    for f=1:handles.nbfile
        shandle=getfield(handles,['slider' int2str(f)]);
        set(shandle,'Value',500);
        rhandle=getfield(handles,['rating' int2str(f)]);
        set(rhandle,'String',500);
    end
    %randomizing the order of the tested files for the next experiment
    handles.file_order=randperm(handles.nbfile);
    %testing whether a break is needed before the next experiment
    if etime(clock,handles.time) > 20*60
        wfig=warndlg(['You have been working for ' int2str(round(etime(clock,handles.time)/60)) 'minutes. It is recommended that you take a break of at least the same duration before starting the next experiment. Click on OK when you are ready.'],'Warning');
        uiwait(wfig);
    end
    handles.time=clock;

    % Start next audio sample
    play_callback(handles,1)

    guidata(gcbf,handles);
else
    %exiting
    close(gcbf);
end

%%%rounding and displaying the values of the sliders
function slider_callback(handles,f)

shandle=getfield(handles,['slider' int2str(f)]);
set(shandle,'Value',round(get(shandle,'Value')));
rhandle=getfield(handles,['rating' int2str(f)]);
set(rhandle,'String',get(shandle,'Value'));
```

As it is right now, the edit field value are not live updated if. The value of the edit field are only updated if the slider is moved and the mouse button is released.

I have tried to add a listener to the slider, but I cannot make it work. So far I have followed the following guides/posts without any luck.

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/continuous-slider-callback
and
https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/140706-use-slider-for-live-updating-of-threshold-on-2d-contour-plot

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener in the `myGUI_OpeningFcn`. Note you need to change `myGUI` to match your GUI script filename.

```
addlistener(handles.slider1,'ContinuousValueChange',@(hObject,eventdata)myGUI('updateText',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)));
```

Then, add the following function in your GUI script.

```
function updateText(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.text2,'String',get(hObject,'Value'));
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

---

More specifically, in your case, you need to add a bunch of listeners:

```
for i=1:handles.nbfile
    addlistener(getfield(handles,['slider' int2str(i)]),'ContinuousValueChange',@(hObject,eventdata)myGUI('updateText',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)));
end
```

Then add:

```
function updateText(hObject, eventdata, handles)
f = hObject.Tag(7:end);
set(getfield(handles,['rating' f]),'String',get(hObject,'Value'));
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

---

**Update**

In your GUI script, add listeners in the `OpeningFcn` (which is the second function automatically generated by Matlab when your GUI was created):

```
for i=1:handles.nbfile
    addlistener(getfield(handles,['slider' int2str(i)]),'ContinuousValueChange',@(hObject,eventdata)myCallBackFileName('updateText',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)));
```

You will need to change `myCallBackFileName` to match the filename of your callback script. Then add the updateText function.

Comment: I am not sure I know how to implement the `myGUI_OpeningFcn`. I have my GUI and callback functions in separate files.. Is it possible for you to give an example of `myGUI_OpeningFcn`?

Comment: Is the GUI script the file where I call `%opening the GUI
    fig=evaluation_gui(nbfile,1,length(attributes_full),attributes_full,highs_full,lows_full);`? Below this line I am setting all my handles... I have three files: 1. A script which setup some files etc. and call the line above and setting the handle. 2. a function which have all the GUI elements and 3. a separate function for the callbacks. Where do I put the `OpeningFcn`? Sorry for being a complete noob, but this is my first time working with Matlab GUI..

Comment: @MikaelKP I see. You did it programmatically rather than using GUIDE. That wise, I'm not very knowledgeable, but you can try add the listener under `function [varargout] = evaluation_gui(vararin)`. This should be the function you call when you want to create your GUI.